# Stationary distribution for a Markov chain which is not irreducible

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process, stationary-processes

I have a Markov chain with $K$ states $S$: {$s_1,s_2,...,s_K$}.

$s_1$ is reachable from any state in $S$; however not all the states can be reached from $s_1$.

What does the stationary distribution of this Markov chain look like?
Does the solution of the function: $$\pi~P=\pi,$$ get the right answer?

Actually, I want to get the expectation of the states by:
$$E=\sum_{s_i\in~S}{\pi_i*s_i}.$$

How can I calculate it correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every stationary distribution $\pi$ solves $\pi P=\pi$ and puts mass zero on the states which $s_1$ does not communicate with. Thus the sum defining the expectation $E$ can omit these states.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! You mean that every resulted $\pi$ may has nonzero values in those states; and I have to manually set them to zero? Moreover how can the $E$ be calculated with multiple $\pi$s?

Comment: ??? I said the opposite: ANY solution of $\pi P=\pi$ has AUTOMATICALLY zeroes at those states.